# Unable to parse json response with python

Tags: python, python-2.x

So I ran into an issue while importing API data into my code. Any help is much appreciated.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
import json, requests

data = requests.get('https://masari.superpools.net/api/live_stats?update=1522693430318').json()
data_parsed = json.loads(open(data,"r").read())
print data_parsed
```

I'm still quite new to python, and I ran into this error:

```
>C:\Users\bot2>python C:\Users\bot2\Desktop\Python_Code\helloworld.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bot2\Desktop\Python_Code\helloworld.py", line 5, in <module>
    data_parsed = json.loads(open(data,"r").read())
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found
```

Comment: You don't need the `open` statement in `json.loads` here; that's just for file reading. Just use `json.loads(data)`. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: @patrick `data` is already a dictionary as `.json()` was added to `request`

Comment: @GüntherJena I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is already received as a json object (which is a `dict` in this case). Just do the following:

```
data = requests.get('https://masari.superpools.net/api/live_stats?update=1522693430318').json()
print data
```

Use `data['network']` for example to access nested dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you, I have an additional question, how would I pull specific data from the API? I would like to pull all data from the category "network" in the API.